# Accessing Route parameters in advanced custom fields Gutenberg blocks callback function

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields' custom Gutenberg blocks and Timber to build out a WordPress site.

I have a few custom routes using Timber's router and would like to access the URL parameters (like `:pg` or `:id`) in my callback function when rendering the custom blocks.

So far, I have been unable to figure out how to do this. I've tried to put the url parameter in the `$context` object, but the value isn't available in the acf callback (I am calling `$context = Timber::context();` inside that function.

I was able to use `Timber\UrlHelper` to get the url path, but that isn't an associative array and doesn't feel very helpful.

TIA.

Comment: could you post a full code snippet?